# How can I add "Loading" text when i click on a button in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the progress bar(Loading) as I know,

```
<svg class="center-block progress-bar-round" width="200" height="200">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="90" fill="none" stroke="#F8F8FF" stroke-width="8"/>
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="90" fill="none" id="loader" class=""
            stroke="#209e91" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="0,20000"
            transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    <text text-anchor="middle" class="loading" x="100" y="90">Loading...</text>
    <text class="percentage" text-anchor="middle" x="100" y="130">{{progress}}%</text>
</svg>
```

In a page, lets say there is "*Continue*" button, but i dont know how to connect this Loading text with that button,
How could I do it?

Comment: Maybe this would help. Stumbled upon it, it relates to dynamically changing button text.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633069/change-button-text-dynamically-in-angularjs)

Comment: Thank you Mr, may you look at my other question too please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68307907/how-can-i-find-the-page-where-ill-do-the-changes-in-angular-js?noredirect=1#comment120724367_68307907

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some kind of boolean in your controller like

```
$scope.loading = false
```

Then in your html your button, and your svg, which is hidden until `$scope.loading` is true with `ng-if`

```
<button ng-click="continue()" ng-if="!loading">Continue</button>

<svg ng-if='loading' class="center-block progress-bar-round" width="200" height="200">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="90" fill="none" stroke="#F8F8FF" stroke-width="8"/>
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="90" fill="none" id="loader" class=""
            stroke="#209e91" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="0,20000"
            transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    <text text-anchor="middle" class="loading" x="100" y="90">Loading...</text>
    <text class="percentage" text-anchor="middle" x="100" y="130">{{progress}}%</text>
</svg>
```

Then finally in your controller

```
$scope.continue = function() {
  $scope.loading = true;
  // do the loading stuff, then when done
  // ...
  $scope.loading = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying Mr, ill try to do this. Could you look at my other question too if u have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68307907/how-can-i-find-the-page-where-ill-do-the-changes-in-angular-js?noredirect=1#comment120724367_68307907

Comment: Btw i meant that I want to show the loading part when i click on "continue" button. When it opens another page it will stop, loading part will be seen till other page opens. Button's text wont be changed. Sorry for my explanation,

Comment: you say another page - is it actually another page or the same page with different content? Are you loading a different view file?

Comment: There are forms. When i click on a continue button, it  shows another form in the same page. i hope i am clear.

Comment: I updated the answer - it is rudimentary but it will work.